# Can I run a local, (Windows) script before network "check-in"?

Tags: windows, boot, script

I am working on a (PoSh) script that may (purposefully) disable NICs.  I will be attempting to re-enable the NICs on shutdown, but as a fail-safe, I want to check and re-enable all NICs on boot.  Obviously, the script to do that needs to be local.

I would really prefer that such a script runs before Windows decides the domain is not reachable (and skips looking for GPOs).

Is this possible?

I'm not looking for the script code to enable NICs; I am hoping there is a method of starting a script very early in the Windows startup process and/or pausing the search for the network until I can make it available.

If not, I guess the worst-case scenario is to find a way to enable and reboot (once) before the login prompt appears.

Update:
I am leaning towards creating a service that will re-enable the NIC(s) and that I can make a dependency of the "tcpip" service.  It looks like stopping a service will also stop the dependent services.  Is there a way to remove a dependency on the fly so the tcpip service can continue to run with out needing an empty service that did it's job sitting around?

Answer (score 0):

Try Computer Startup Scripts to see the result.

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770556(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: A GPO startup script definitely isn't going to cut it.  First, without a network connection, the GPO won't be read.  Second, even if a machine follows the GPO as it was the last time it booted *and* the script is local (not the default for GPOs), GPO scripts are run last so that will occur well after the machine has determined the domain is not reachable.  I'm looking for a way to run a script *before* all of that.